# I am trying to compile a simple string but it does not work... why?

Tags: c++, compilation, strstr

My compiler is Code::Blocks. I am trying to eliminate vocals from a character sequence.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
char sir[256];
int i=0;

int main (){
cout<<"sir=";cin.getline(sir,256);
for (i=strlen(sir);i>0;i--){
    if (strstr(sir[i],'aeiou')==0){
        strcpy(sir+i,sir+i+1);
        break;}}
cout<<"sir="<<sir<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
error: call of overloaded 'strstr(char&, int)' is ambiguous
note: candidates are:
note: char* strstr(char*, cost char*) near match
```

But I think the problem is on strstr command...

Comment: 'aeiou' is not a string-literal. you mean "aeiou" but that also would be wrong because it would find all of them not each of them.

Comment: What is 'aeiou'? If it is a substring you should use double quotes around it

Comment: `strstr` looks for a substring; in the C library you would probably want `strchr`, but in C++ the functionality is called `find_first_of`.

Comment: The question is: ***Why are you trying to use old C strings in C++, having the beautiful `std::string` class?***

Answer (score 1):

'aeiou' is not a string literal in c/c++ use "aeiou".
In c/c++ string literal are represented inside " "(double quotes)

[Read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, the idea is to remove vowels. As others have said, use `"aeiou"` and not `'aeiou'`. But you also need to use the right function to check whether you have a vowel. That's `strchr(const char* s, int c)`, not `strstr`. `strchr` looks for an occurrence of `c` in the string that `s` points to, and returns a pointer to that occurrence, or, if it's not found, a pointer to the terminating nil character. So the test in the original code should be:

```
if (*strchr("aeiou", sir[i] != '\0')
```

Personally, I'd write this a bit more succinctly:

```
if (*strchr("aeiou", sir[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the first comment, the expression

```
strstr(sir[i],'aeiou')
```

is wrong for two reasons: ' is for single characters, " is for strings, but the main reason is, that strstr finds the occurance of the whole thing, not of the characters separately.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
char sir[256];
char sir2[256];
int i=0;

int main (){
    cout<<"sir=";cin.getline(sir,256);
    char* reader = sir;
    char* writer = sir2;
    while(*reader) {
        if(*reader!='a' && *reader!='e' && *reader!='i' && *reader!='o' && *reader!='u') {
            *writer = *reader;
            ++writer;
        }
        ++reader;
    }
    *writer = '\0';
    cout<<"sir="<<sir2<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ststr is defined by two function prototypes

```
const char* strstr( const char* str, const char* target );

      char* strstr(       char* str, const char* target );
```

your call is calling  as

```
strstr(sir[i],'aeiou')
```

the first arg is a char  type, not a char * type, so the compiler does know how to map that to const char * or char *

Also check your loop index as

```
 i=strlen(sir)
```

will over index the char array and

```
i > 0
```

will NOT access  the last character.